# showing derived mongo documents based on values of an array in a single mongo db record

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a mongo db record in a table car with structure like given below

```
name: Ferrari
color: [ red, blue, green ]
```

How would I run a find query in mongo db that would display one record each for the values present in color ?
Sample Output:

```
name: Ferrari
color: red
```

```
name: Ferrari
color: blue
```

```
name: Ferrari
color: green
```

Comment: It looks like you need `$unwind` but it has to be used within `.aggregate()`. Is that what you're looking for? https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It better if you take a look about [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/), it's actually what you looking for. Here is example how to use it.

Let's say you have collection that include this:

```
[
  { "_id" : 1, "item" : "ABC", price: NumberDecimal("80"), "sizes": [ "S", "M", "L"] },
  { "_id" : 2, "item" : "EFG", price: NumberDecimal("120"), "sizes" : [ ] },
  { "_id" : 3, "item" : "IJK", price: NumberDecimal("160"), "sizes": "M" },
  { "_id" : 4, "item" : "LMN" , price: NumberDecimal("10") },
  { "_id" : 5, "item" : "XYZ", price: NumberDecimal("5.75"), "sizes" : null }
]
```

you can get the result for same _id but each size from `sizes` , so you can do it by running one of the two options:

```
db.inventory2.aggregate( [ { $unwind: "$sizes" } ] )
db.inventory2.aggregate( [ { $unwind: { path: "$sizes" } } ] )
```

then you will get:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "item" : "ABC", "price" : NumberDecimal("80"), "sizes" : "S" }
{ "_id" : 1, "item" : "ABC", "price" : NumberDecimal("80"), "sizes" : "M" }
{ "_id" : 1, "item" : "ABC", "price" : NumberDecimal("80"), "sizes" : "L" }
{ "_id" : 3, "item" : "IJK", "price" : NumberDecimal("160"), "sizes" : "M" }
```

But what important to you is to get custom result but other object.. You can use `$match` to complete you query, using **aggregate** you can get the specific result. Lets say you want to find the item "ABC" and split all sizes for that specific item:

```
db.inventory2.aggregate( [
//Stage one - find items named "ABC"
 {$match:{"item":"ABC"}},
//Stage two - split result of sizes array
{ $unwind: "$sizes" } 
] )
```

The result for that query is:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "item" : "ABC", "price" : NumberDecimal("80"), "sizes" : "S" }
{ "_id" : 1, "item" : "ABC", "price" : NumberDecimal("80"), "sizes" : "M" }
{ "_id" : 1, "item" : "ABC", "price" : NumberDecimal("80"), "sizes" : "L" }
```

By using **aggregate** you can query by steps and make changes in your result, but since you using some extra filters, the result will take more time from normal query.